# How to enable Markdown in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, markdown

I installed the IDEA-MARKDOWN in IntelliJ 13.1.5 and restarted. I Added some markdown to a class's javadocs, but I don't see a bold title when I press on the class name CTRL-Q, I only see the "H2 Title" in bold:

```
/**
 * ## H1 Title
 * <h2>H2 Title</h2>
 */
public class Test {

}
```

Answer (score 6):

To properly render Markdown Javadoc comments, I think you need the [Pegdown Doclet for IDEA](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7253?pr=idea) plugin.

Comment: I tried installing it in 13.1.5 and got this error on restart: Unknown macro: $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$ in storage spec: $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/pegdown-doclet.xml. I tried installing it in 14.x and got some class not found or another error. I don't think this plugin is needed because it has very few downloads.

Comment: Despite the error, it does seem to work... but on 14.x it's disabled because of the error.

Comment: And the error dialog keep popping up periodically in 13.1.5.